# how to change banner button text, based on array index in a carousel (.twig)

Tags: for-loop, indexing, twig

My current slideshow.twig for a 4 banner carousel is the following

```
<div class="swiper-viewport">
<div id="slideshow{{ module }}" class="swiper-container">{% set i = 1 %}
<div class="swiper-wrapper"> {% for banner in banners %}

  <div class="swiper-slide s-slide-{{ i }} text-center">

  <img src="{{ banner.image }}" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

  <div class="banner-desc">{{ banner.title }}

 {% if banner.link %}<a class="btn-slider" href="{{ banner.link }}">SHOP NOW</a>

 {% endif %}
```

Instead of having every single banner in the slideshow display "Shop Now", how could I modify my if statement line to change the text for the first and third indexes of this array to show "Read More"?

Comment: Bit offtopic but why don't just add a `label`-property to your banners? Then u could do `<a ...>{{ banner.label }}</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation of the `for` tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html), you can access the loop index using `loop.index` (begins from `1`) or `loop.index0` (begins from `0`). So you can do:

```
{% if banner.link %}
    <a class="btn-slider" href="{{ banner.link }}">
        {% if loop.index in [1, 3] %}
            READ MORE
        {% else %}
            SHOP NOW
        {% endif %}
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

Or using the ternary operator:

```
{% if banner.link %}
    <a class="btn-slider" href="{{ banner.link }}">
        {{ loop.index in [1, 3] ? 'READ MORE' : 'SHOP NOW' }}
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

Furthermore, if you are defining the `i` variable to just keep track of the loop index, you can get rid of it and instead do it this way:

```
<div class="swiper-slide s-slide-{{ loop.index }} text-center">
```

Then you don't need to manually increment the variable (with `{% set i = i + 1 %}` at the end of each loop).